# Beautifullsoup getting part of string from class

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

The HTML is :

```
<div class="_3u1 _gli _uvb" data-bt='{"id":xxxx,"rank":11,"abtest_version":null,"abtest_params":{"abtest_version":null,"origin":"A","ranker":null},"section":"main_column","owner_id":null,"sub_id":null,"browse_location":null,"query_data":[],"is_headline":false}'>
```

**My code is :**

```
for profileid in soup.find_all("div","_3u1 _gli _uvb"):
    for fbid in profileid.find_all("data-bt"):
        worksheet.write(row,0,fbid.get("id"))
        print (fbid.get("id"))
        row += 1
```

**the return i get is :**

```
 {"id":xxxxxx,"rank":1,"abtest_version":null,"abtest_params":{"abtest_version":null,"origin":"A","ranker":null},"section":"main_column","owner_id":null,"sub_id":null,"browse_location":null,"query_data":[],"is_headline":false}
```

How could i just get the `xxxxx` returned? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse `data-bt` since it contains valid `json`.

```
import json

found =  soup.find_all("div", "_3u1 _gli _uvb")

for fbid in found:
    ...
    bt_json = json.loads(fbid.attrs['data-bt'])
    print(bt_json['id'])
    ...
```

Comment: Good answer! Thanks for using json instead of parsing it as a string.